# How to Retrive Data From The Database and Display in listview with multiple checkboxes?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Hello Everyone please help me with this code...

Here i am Retriving the Data from the database and displaying it on the listview with checkboxes...

The problem is, I am Retriving the Name of the Students from "attendrecords" table but its not displaying the student's name on listview,instead of its displaying the TextView in place of every name in listview.
Below is My Code Please Help...
Thanks in Advance..

File First ...

TakeAttend.java

```
package com.example.myattendance;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TakeAttend extends Activity {

public Button save_attendance;
public Button cancel;
public ListView take_attend_list;
public TextView textView;
public ArrayList<String> attendList;
DatabaseHandler handler;
MyAdapter adapter;
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.take_attend);

    save_attendance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    take_attend_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.take_attend_list);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout_textview);

    handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    attendList = new ArrayList<String>();
    attendList = handler.getdata();

    adapter = new MyAdapter(TakeAttend.this,attendList);
    take_attend_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        //  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,attendList);

    //take_attend_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    //take_attend_list.setAdapter(adapter);


    save_attendance.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(TakeAttend.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(TakeAttend.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}`
```

Second File ...

MyAdapter.java...

```
package com.example.myattendance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.Status;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public TakeAttend takeAttend;
ArrayList<String> attendList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public MyAdapter(TakeAttend takeAttend, ArrayList<String> attendList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.takeAttend = takeAttend;
    this.attendList = attendList;
    inflater = inflater.from(takeAttend);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int size = attendList.size();
    return size;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.attend_layout, null);
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_checkBox);

    box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Toast.makeText(takeAttend, "" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    return v;
}

}
```

Third File ....

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.myattendance;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NewAttendance";
//private static final String TABLE_NAME = "records";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE attndrecords(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,firstname TEXT,middlename TEXT,lastname TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST : attndrecords");
    onCreate(db);
//db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST :"+TABLE_NAME);   
}

public void savedata(String fname,String mname,String lname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("firstname", fname);
    values.put("middlename", mname);
    values.put("lastname", lname);

    db.insert("attndrecords", null, values);

    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> getdata()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM attndrecords", null);
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM attndrecords", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return list;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , u need to create TextView for each record in your adapter . You are just getting only the check box . More over , you should get data from your attendent list for each row , and then just update the TextView with the name of student (every thing is inside the Adapter)

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.attend_layout, null);
    // Get current value
    String currentAttendent = attendList.Get(position);
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_checkBox);
    // Create TextView
    TextView txt = (TextView) v.findVIewByID(R.id.layout_YourTextViewName) 
    //Set value                                                                      
    txt.SetText(currentAttendent);
    box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Toast.makeText(takeAttend, "" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    return v;
}

}
```

ok so you need to create your own SQLiteOpenHelper class , you can find tutorial [for example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) . Then you need to provide me some more data , when you want to save data to  the datebase ?
I'll show you how to do it on every check of `CheckBox` , but you should rather do it on button click or something like that it would be more efficient way. I can see that you've got some DateBaseHandler but I'm not aware how your are using it . Please provide some more info , it'd easier to help you then.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public TakeAttend takeAttend;
ArrayList<String> attendList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
//Add new variables Context and your custom SQLiteOpenHelper 
Context context ;
DateBaseHelper DBHelper; // you need to create this class first
public MyAdapter(TakeAttend takeAttend, ArrayList<String> attendList , Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.takeAttend = takeAttend;
    this.attendList = attendList;
    inflater = inflater.from(takeAttend);
    this.context = Context;
    DBHelper = new DateBaseHelper(context); // initialize DateBase helper

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int size = attendList.size();
    return size;
}
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.attend_layout, null);
        // Get current value
        final String currentAttendent = attendList.Get(position);
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_checkBox);
        // Create TextView
        TextView txt = (TextView) v.findVIewByID(R.id.layout_YourTextViewName) 

       //Setvalue                                                                      
        txt.SetText(currentAttendent);
        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked == true){
                   DBHelper.insert(currentAttendent);
                 }
                else{
                   // it depends on how you'd implement DateBaseHelper
                   long ID = DBHelper.GetID(currentAttendent);
                   DBHelper.delete(ID);
                    }

            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    }
```

And change your Activity to :

```
package com.example.myattendance;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TakeAttend extends Activity {

public Button save_attendance;
public Button cancel;
public ListView take_attend_list;
public TextView textView;
public ArrayList<String> attendList;
DatabaseHandler handler;
MyAdapter adapter;
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.take_attend);

    save_attendance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    take_attend_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.take_attend_list);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout_textview);

    handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    attendList = new ArrayList<String>();
    attendList = handler.getdata();

    adapter = new MyAdapter(TakeAttend.this,attendList,this); //'this' means context
    take_attend_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        //  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,attendList);

    //take_attend_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    //take_attend_list.setAdapter(adapter);


    save_attendance.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(TakeAttend.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(TakeAttend.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hubert its working.... Can you please help me with one more thing... i want to save the data of all the selected checkboxes into the database along with the current date and time... for that what i need to do ?

Comment: @Pavan please check out the edit , which i've made. It was hard to answer because you did not provide much information , but I hope it'll help you. Ask if you've got any questions.

Comment: In detail this is a mini project of attendance taking system in which a lecturer press a take_attendance_button and the list of all the students from the database will get display in a listview along with the checkbox as we did it so far... now when any lecturer will take attendance then he/she will check the checkbox if student is present otherwise blank.... after taking attendance lecturer is going to press on the save button...here i want to save the data of all the selected and unselected checkboxes into the database inside table name studentrecord which contains fieldname id and status...

Comment: in which id represents the id of student and Status 1 represent student is present and status 0 represent student is absent.... like if the checkbox is checked then in the status field 1 will get enter and if the box is unchecked then in the status field 0 will get enter... i have to do it on save_button click...